# Using a generic argument in a generic method parameter created by CodeDOM

Tags: c#, codedom

I am trying to create a generic method through code dome where the generic argument is used in the method parameter, for example:

```
String.Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)
```

I have a bit of code to generate the parameters that looks like this:

```
foreach (var parameter in method.GetParameters())
{
    Type parameterType = parameter.ParameterType;

    this.VerifyTypeIsKnown(parameterType, typeSet, parameter.Name, "Parameter");

    globalNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport(parameterType.Namespace));

    var memberParameter = new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(parameterType, parameter.Name);

    memberMethod.Parameters.Add(memberParameter);
}
```

However this incorrectly generates:

```
string Join<T>(string separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<> values)
        ;
```

Where the T in IEnumerable is missing.

I have tried to add the following in order to force add the generic parameters:

```
foreach (var generic in parameterType.GetGenericArguments())
{
    var typeref = new CodeTypeReference(generic, CodeTypeReferenceOptions.GenericTypeParameter);
    memberParameter.Type.TypeArguments.Add(typeref);
}
```

However, this produces a copy of 1', causing the output code to look like this:

```
string Join<T>(string separator, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`1 values)
        ;
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong, or how to correctly generate the parameters when using generic arguments?

Answer (score 4):

Found a solutions, for next person who gets stock on this:

```
foreach (var parameter in method.GetParameters())
{
    Type parameterType = parameter.ParameterType;

    this.VerifyTypeIsKnown(parameterType, typeSet, parameter.Name, "Parameter");

    globalNamespace.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport(parameterType.Namespace));

    var typeArguments = from param in parameterType.GetGenericArguments()
                        select new CodeTypeReference(param);
    var memberParameterType = new CodeTypeReference(parameterType.Name, typeArguments.ToArray<CodeTypeReference>());

    var memberParameter = new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(memberParameterType, parameter.Name);

    memberMethod.Parameters.Add(memberParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its only one line code..

```
 foreach (var parameter in method.GetParameters())
 {
   memberMethod.Parameters.Add(new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression(parameter.ParameterType.Name, parameter.Name));
 }
```